# Bite/byte addressing in MIPS

Tags: mips

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am currently taking an intro to computer architecture/organization course and the textbook we are using is called *Computer Organization and Design by David Patterson and John Hennessey (5th Edition)* and they list an example of how to access elements in an array using MIPS. The example they list goes something like this:

Given the C code assignment: g = h + A[8]; convert the following to MIPS.
  Where g = $s1, h = $s2, and the obase address A = $s3.

They go on to say that the MIPS instructions that represent the same instruction in C code are as follows:

```
 (1) lw $t0, 8($s3) # Temporary register $t0 gets A[8]
 (2) add $s1,$s2,$t0 # g = h +A[8]
```

Then on another page, the authors mention that line (1) could have also been written as:

```
(3) lw $t0,32($s3)
```

My question is what is the difference between lines (1) and (3) and why is that important?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What pages are these excepts on? I have the same edition. This doesn't sound correct. If you wanted the 8th word in an array of words you need the offset to be index*word size, which would be 8*4 = 32.

Comment: Don't know why the author said those 2 lines were equivalent, `32($s3)` loads the 8th word from register `$s3` while `8($s3)` just loads the 2nd word, so the 8th element in the array is accessed at **32 + the base address which is $s3 which is 32($s3)**. In one word, those 2 lines are **not** equivalent

Comment: Pages 69,71,and 72

Comment: Mr. avenger12, nobody here has that book so page numbers aren't going to help much. The only way you could have written line 3 instead of line 1 and have it do the same thing is if the address in register `$s3` were different. My guess is that's what's missing: Perhaps there was already an address in `$s3`, and it's known to be 24 bytes less than the address of `A`, and rather than load the address of `A` into `$s3` just to then load `8($s3)`, instead, forego loading the address of `A` into `$s3` and just load `32($s3)` instead, saving an instruction. That's my guess.

Comment: So it occurred to me that perhaps you're *Ms.* avenger12; no offense intended if that is the case.

Comment: @phonetagher Thanks for your insight. What you say makes sense, but the book says that $s3 in both cases contains the the obase adress of the array A. Haha no worries Im a Mr.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could have written line 3 instead of line 1 and have it do the same thing is if the address in register `$s3` were different. My guess is that's what's missing: Perhaps there was already an address in `$s3`, and it's known to be 24 bytes less than the address of `A`, and rather than load the address of `A` into `$s3` just to then load `8($s3)`, instead, forego loading the address of A into `$s3` and just load `32($s3)` instead, saving an instruction. That's my guess.